# Gerar e apagar linhas de uma tabela com JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Fiz uma função que gera linhas em uma tabela mas não estou conseguindo apaga-las.

Alguém poderia me dizer como eu consigo adicionar e remover toda vez que eu clicar nos botões?

Função que gera as linhas

```
var i = 0;

$('#addRow').click(function(){
    // GERA UMA PROXIMA LINHA
    $('<tr id="t_row'+i+'">'+
        '<th></th>'+
        '<td>'+periodo[i]+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
    '</tr>').appendTo('tbody');

    i++;


    // PARA O BOTAO QUANDO CHEGAR NO 12
    if(i == 12){
        $('#addRow').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    return false;

});
```

Função que remove as linhas

```
$('#delRow').click(function(){

    $('t_row'+i).remove();  

    i--;

    return false;
});
```

Botões HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow" >Adicionar linha</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delRow">Apagar linha</button>
</div>
```

Tabela HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Meses</th>
                <th scope="col">Periodo</th>
                <th scope="col">Demanda(Y)</th>
                <th scope="col">X</th>
                <th scope="col">X<sup>2</sup></th>
                <th scope="col">X*Y</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot style="background-color: #009127;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" id="total_1">...</th>
                <th scope="col">...</th>
                <th scope="col" id="total_2">...</th>
                <th scope="col" id="total_3">...</th>
                <th scope="col" id="total_4">...</th>
                <th scope="col" id="total_5">...</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Onde você define o `i` do `$('#delRow').click`? Imagino que ele esteja fazendo o seguinte `$('t_rowundefined').remove()`

Comment: Esta como global. Acabei me esquecendo de mostra-la.

Comment: Coloca a tabela com algum dado, por favor.

Comment: Carlos falta o # em `$('t_row'+i).remove(); `, deveria ser `$('#t_row'+i).remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem dois problemas no seu script. O primeiro é que o i está sendo decrementado depois de remover a linha, logo ele vai tentar decrementar uma linha que ainda não foi criada. O segundo é que você colocou `$('t_row'+i).remove();`, logo não está se referindo a nenhum elemento, para acessar o id, faltou o #. Segue exemplo com o script corrigido:

```js
var i = 0;

$('#addRow').click(function(){
    // GERA UMA PROXIMA LINHA
    $('<tr id="t_row'+i+'">'+
        '<th></th>'+
        '<td>teste'+i+'</td>'+
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
        '<td></td>'+
    '</tr>').appendTo('tbody');
    i++;
    // PARA O BOTAO QUANDO CHEGAR NO 12
    if(i == 12){
        $('#addRow').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    return false;
});

$('#delRow').click(function(){
    i--;
    $('#t_row'+i).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow" >Adicionar linha</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delRow">Apagar linha</button>
</div>
```

Outro problema é que você não colocou um ponto de parada no decremento, o que pode fazer o i ficar negativo e isso criar mais do que 12 linhas, já que ele iria de -n até 12.